# Using Illinois Chunker

Tags: java, nlp

I am trying to extract noun phrases from text using the [illinois chunker](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Chunker) however i seem to be getting something wrong. I am trying to run the command in a centos6.4 system with jdk1.8 having downloaded the jar given in the link.

```
java -Xmx512m -classpath /path/to/LBJChunk.jar edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.lbj.chunk.ChunksAndPOSTags snippeting.txt
```

this returns a class not found exception, what am i doing wrong >:( do i have to download an other jar for the parser?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LBJ2/parse/Parser
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2937)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LBJ2.parse.Parser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: I think you should replace '/path/to/LBJChunk.jar' with the right path to LBJChunker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need some more jars on the classpath. It's not very clear, but the description for the chunker notes that LBJ (a language library) and the Illinois POS tagger are required. You can get more information on how to run it [here.](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/chunker)

Then, run this command:

```
java -classpath /path/to/LBJChunk.jar:/path/to/LBJ2Library.jar:/path/toLBJPOS.jar \
      edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.lbj.chunk.ChunksAndPOSTags snippeting.txt
```

That should work!

Comment: The link is broken. Can you help here, please? @CogComp-NLP